# qsort array of structs descending order

Tags: c, arrays, struct, comparator, qsort

I have a struct that looks like this

```
typedef struct id_score{
   int id;
   int score;
} pair;
```

An array of size 50 holds pointers to these pairs

```
pair* array[50]
```

My comparator function looks like this

```
int struct_cmp(const void *a, const void* b) {
    pair* ia = (pair*)a;
    pair* ib = (pair*)b;
    printf("ia's score: %d ib's score: %d??? \n", ia->score, ib->score);
    return ib->score - ia->score;
}
```

My qsort function here

```
size_t arr_len = sizeof(array) / sizeof(pair);
qsort(array, arr_len, sizeof(pair), struct_cmp);
```

Now my problem is that in the `struct_cmp` function, my `printf` shows that the values that I think should be the count in each struct in the array are all interpreted as `0`, thus not sorting the array at all. Outside of the function when I print through the array, the struct's have scores that it should have.

Any suggestions?? thank you!

Comment: Is not `a` in a pointer to the element? The array elements are type `pair*` So `pair** ia = (pair**)a;`?

Comment: You're sorting an array of pointers; your comparator is passed a pair of pointers to pointers, not single level pointers.  If you were sorting an array of `int`, your function would be passed two `int *`.  Since you're sorting an array of `pair *`, your function is passed two `pair **`.

Comment: Note: When you call `qsort()`, consider `qsort(array, arr_len, sizeof *array, struct_cmp);`  This is easier to code, review, and maintain than `qsort(..., ..., sizeof(pair), ...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For one

```
size_t arr_len = sizeof(array) / sizeof(pair);
```

The above is wrong, as your array contains `pair` pointers, and not `pair`s. Doing it a bit more idiomatically and with less repetition would be:

```
size_t arr_len = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
```

Another thing to note, is that your comparison function converts to the wrong pointer type, so the behavior of your program is undefined.

Remember that the callback function will receive pointers to array elements, so if the array contains pointers, it should convert the arguments to pointers to pointers:

```
int struct_cmp(const void *a, const void* b) {
    pair* const * ia = (pair* const *)a;
    pair* const * ib = (pair* const *)b;
    printf("ia's score: %d ib's score: %d??? \n", ia->score, ib->score);
    return (*ib)->score - (*ia)->score;
}
```

Unlike your original function, I also strove to make it const correct. The compare callback accepts by a pointer to const, so the converted pointer should be to const as well (with const being applied to the element type, which is `pair*`).

---

As **chux** pointed out, as a way to avoid overflow in the subtraction, a major improvement will be to return the following instead:

```
return ((*ib)->score > (*ia)->score) - ((*ib)->score < (*ia)->score);
```

Which also has the nice property of always returning -1, 0 or 1 instead of arbitrary numbers.

Comment: To avoid overflow in the subtraction, could use `(a>b) - (a< b)` idiom.

Comment: @chux - Added. And thank you for making me aware of the idioms existence :)

Comment: My understanding is that compilers look for it too, so a reasonable chance to emit tight code.  Yet for me, it plugs a functional hole vs. `return a-b`.  Nice bit about the `const` correct.  LSNED

Comment: I guess my biggest error came from `return ib->score - ia->score;
}` ??

Comment: @namesake22 The biggest problems IMO were those that are unlikely to break your program immediately. Such as the array size issue. The wrong pointer conversion would have vexed you until you solved it.